# How we can compare loss and metrics evaluated on different sizes of training and validation sets?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, cross-validation

Let `N_train`, `N_val` and `N_test` are the number of examples in training, validation, and test sets.

As I understood, in general these values are taken as `N_train >> N_val ~= N_test`.

As I understood, the loss and metrics are evaluated (in an average sense) on the whole training set. In this context, how can we compare the performance on sets of different sizes?

Why isn't it like model performance is evaluated on a subset of the training set whose size is comparable to that of the validation or test set?

One can argue that it might increase the computational cost, but we can at least draw (randomly) from the losses evaluated during the training step.

Please let me know if there are any reasons behind this approach!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in ML is that you always have too little data.
If you would have more, you would be able to improve the performance of your model.
Therefore, you want to waste as little data as possible, which comes down to getting as much samples in the training data as possible.

The problem with putting all data in the training set is that you will be unable to say how good your model actually works on *unseen* data (the generalisation performance).
That is where test (and validation) data comes into play.
By taking away some of the data that you could use for training, you can create a dataset of unseen samples to estimate the generalisation performance of your model.
This means that you sacrifice some of the data you could have improved your model with to tell how good your model will be.

This creates a trade-off between training and evaluation:

- you need as much training data as possible for improving the model. However, if all data would be used for training, we will not be able to estimate its generalisation performance.
- you want to have as much test data as possible to get a better estimate of the generalisation performance of your model. However, if all data would be used for evaluation, our models would essentially have to make random predictions.

Since it is typically more important to get a good model than estimating its performance, the training dataset will be larger than the test (and validation) dataset.
Therefore, the test set would be a small (the smallest possible) subset of data that represents the data distribution well enough to obtain reasonable estimates and the rest of the data makes up the training dataset.
Note that this also assumes that the dataset is large enough and is somewhat clean.
E.g. if there would be a class that has only 1 sample, it would not be possible/meaningful to extract a test set, or at least you would not be able to assess the generalisation performance for this class.

That is why you will normally have more training than test (or validation) data.
Metrics can be compared because they are typically averaged over the number of samples.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, in general these values are taken as N_train >> N_val ~= N_test.

> As I understood, the loss and metrics are evaluated (in an average sense) on the whole training set. In this context, how can we compare the performance on sets of different sizes?

- usually, the *training* data loss is used as part of the training algorithm, but not for establishing generalization performance.
- performance estimates are usually calculated in a manner that makes them independent of the test sample size, e.g. root *mean* squared error, fractions of tested cases such as fraction of correct predictions.
  More precisely, their point estimates are independent of the number of tested cases, confidence intervals will (and should) depend on the number of tested cases.

> Why isn't it like model performance is evaluated on a subset of the training set whose size is comparable to that of the validation or test set?

Sample size requirements for model training and testing are largely independent of each other.  For model training, often the number of training cases relative to model complexity (e.g. number of variates) is the crucial point. In addition, we can adapt e.g. via regularization or ensemble predictions to small sample size/high dimensionality situations.

In contrast, the precision of test results depends on the *absolute* number of tested cases.

From this it makes sense that typically tests used for hyperparameter optimization and final tests (to estimate generalization performance of the obtained model) are designed to have (approximately) equal sample size.

Training error, i.e. the loss function used for parameter fitting, is a totally different beast. But since the actual testing of an available caes is hardly any computational effort (compared to training), and since the test results are more precise with larger sample size, one may as well use all the cases assigned for training to evaluate the loss function during training. Outside that scope, training error is often almost useless anyways since it does not detect overfitting.

> One can argue that it might increase the computational cost, but we can at least draw (randomly) from the losses evaluated during the training step.

The point here is that once the parameters have been fitted with the help of the loss calculations, they are hardly ever useful. Often the performance metrics for training data are available, but one ignores them because they don't provide useful information.